# Is promoting an event that occurs on Shabbat a prohibited source of income?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, employment

Is promoting an event that occurs on Shabbat a prohibited source of income? For instance, if your employer wants you to contact various organizations and have them participate in an event set for Saturday morning, or Friday evening.

My gut feeling tells me it's prohibited, but I thought I'd ask to be sure.

Comment: If you want to be sure you should ask your local rabbi. We can't tell you what the Halacha is in your scenario, as we are not your rabbi (or anyone's for that matter)

Comment: Is the employer Jewish? If so, the employer is making money on Shabbat, besides possibly violating other Shabbat prohibitions during the event (music, electronics, etc.) If he is Gentile, what's the problem?

Comment: Employer is gentile, but you are responsible for convincing people to participate. With so many people, you have no idea who's Jewish, who's not.